# Ggplot based on subset values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

If you want to filter and create a new column that selects the values bellow 2 for df$Length - df$P.

(I don't want to create a new subset, but process it "on the fly" I know dplyr has some functionality for this)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter((df$Length - df$P) <= 2) %>%
df$ap<-(df$Length - df$P)
grouped <- df %>% group_by(ap, Style) %>% summarise(BD2_mean=mean(BD2), BD2_top=quantile(BD2, 0.95), BD2_bottom=quantile(BD2, 0.05))

grouped %>% ggplot(aes(x=ap)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=BD2_bottom, ymax=BD2_top), alpha=0.5, color='#00FF7F', fill='#90EE90', size=1.05) +
  geom_line(aes(y=BD2_mean), size=1.1, color='#3CB371', linetype='longdash', alpha=0.7) +
  ggtitle('Grouped Line Plot') +
  xlab('AP') + ylab('BD2') + facet_grid(Style~.)
```

Comment: Please `dput()` your `df` to make a reproducible example

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter and create a new column, try

```
df %>% filter((Length - P) <= 2) %>% mutate(ap = Length - P)
```

If you also want to re-assign the result to `df`, you can use the [assignment pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html) `%<>%`, like

```
df %<>% filter((Length - P) <= 2) %>% mutate(ap = Length - P)
```